# React function component renders Renders on focus

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have problem with re-rendering. Every time user focuses on input it's re-rendering, even on input. Every time user types one word, function component re-renders, but I have big data and it makes everything very slow because of that.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [containerID, setContainerID] = useState();
  const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log("its rendering again")}
      <input
        onInput={(e) => setSearchVal(e.currentTarget.value)}
        onFocus={(e) => setContainerID(e.currentTarget.id)}
        id={1}
      />
      <input
        onInput={(e) => setSearchVal(e.currentTarget.value)}
        onFocus={(e) => setContainerID(e.currentTarget.id)}
        id={2}
      />
      <input
        onInput={(e) => setSearchVal(e.currentTarget.value)}
        onFocus={(e) => setContainerID(e.currentTarget.id)}
        id={3}
      />
      <input
        onInput={(e) => setSearchVal(e.currentTarget.value)}
        onFocus={(e) => setContainerID(e.currentTarget.id)}
        id={4}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Not a single function starts working just renders function return section on every focus and input. Any ideas how to stop these unwanted renders? Here is code snippet also:

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-germain-t0h8n?file=/src/App.js:0-962

Comment: Try useMemo on the component that has that big data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing state causes re-renders. You can use useRef to avoid this issue. You will get values in `containerId.current` and `searchValue.current`.

```
export default function App() {

    const containerId = useRef();
    const searchValue = useRef();
    
    return (
      <input
            onInput={(e) => searchValue.current = e.currentTarget.value}
            onFocus={(e) => containerId.current = e.currentTarget.id}
            id={1}
          />
    );

}
```

Comment: thanks, one problem solved but i need to have useState hook couse i'm changing table container elements but whole table re-renders again

Comment: can you share your whole code structure? In that way, I can understand the real problem. On focus and On Input re-render issue should have been solved by using useRef.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-shockley-espzn?file=/src/App.js here it is but it must render mustNotRender div in some cases its not static data, but its rendering anytime mustRenderDiv changes

Comment: separate your components and use useMemo, React.memo, useCallBack...Try to see these concepts. Then I think you can solve your problem. Thank you.